# Description of Sdictionary file format

Tags: open-source, dictionary

I'm looking for a Sdictionary file format description and eventually parser/convertor for it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

http://sdict.com/en/format.php

Comment: Thanks for this, I was more interested in description of the binary format, so I can decompile existing dictionaries.